# I want to make a new array from existing one

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

My problem today is about creating an array from an existing one.
My "parent" array contains elements with two characters.
My new array's elements should contain 20 elements from the "parent" array.

*Example:*

```
string[] parentArray = {aa, bb, cc, df, ds, aa, zz, xx, cc, ww, fg, qq, ww, ee, 
                key:    (0) (1) (2) (3) (4) (6) (7) (8) (9) (10)........ rr, dd, ss, qq, dd, ss, sa, wq, ee, rr}   
string[] childArray = {aabbccdfdsaazzxxccwwfgqqwweerrddssqqddss,.....}
                                         (1)
```

Comment: This sounds like an assignment, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds like a good match for LINQ with `Select`: `indexes.Select(index => array[index]).ToArray()`.

Comment: FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\*****\Desktop\textFile.txt", FileMode.Open);
string[] hexx = new string[fs.Length];
for (int i = 0; (hexIn = fs.ReadByte()) != -1; i++)
            {
                hexx[i] = string.Format("{0:X2}", hexIn);
            }
from here i have array called hexx. It conteints elements, each one with the characters. i want to make a new array witch element is made by 20 of this elements, from the 1st array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some of the extension functions for enumerables you can go a long way here.

```
int cursor = 0;
List<string> result = new List<string>();
while (cursor < parentArray.Length)
{
    result.Add(String.Join("", parentArray.Skip(cursor).Take(20)));
    cursor += 20;
}
string[] childArray = result.ToArray();
```

This function walks over your array, fetches 20 elements (or less in case there aren't 20 elements left) and merges them into a string and add that string to a list. I made use of the [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/System.String.Join(v=VS.110).aspx) method to concat the string. That works nicely here.

The `Skip` function and the `Take` function are extension functions for `IEnumerable` and do just what they say.

*EDIT:* I did assume that your source array is longer and may contain multiple blocks of 20 elements that need to be moved to the `childArray`

*EDIT2:*  In case you have a load of values in your `parentArray` you may want to go a different way, to get some more performance out of it. In that case I suggest using the [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/System.Text.StringBuilder(v=VS.110).aspx).

```
var builder = new Text.StringBuilder();
List<string> result = new List<string>();
for (int cursor = 0; cursor < parentArray.Length; cursor++)
{
    if (builder.Length > 0 && (cursor % 20) == 0)
    {
        result.Add(builder.ToString());
        builder.Length = 0;
    }
    builder.Append(parentArray[cursor]);
}
/* At this point you can choose to add the remaining elements to the list or not. */
if (builder.Length > 0)
{
    result.Add(builder.ToString());
}
string[] childArray = result.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds as if a simple LINQ-statement will do what you need:

```
var myArr = parent.Take(20).ToArray();
```

This will select the 20 first elements of your `parent`-array.

EDIT: To do this with all of your elements within `parent` loop its entries:

```
List<string> result= new List<string>();
while(parent.Any()) {
    result.Add(String.Join("", parent.Take(20).ToArray());
    parent = parent.Skip(20).ToArray();
}
```

Finally convert your list back to an array using `result.ToArray`.

Comment: So you want to aggregate groups of 20 elements from the `parent`-array, right?

Comment: @HimBromBeere This solution will run into performance issues pretty fast for many items. Starting with the second iteration `Skip` can't optimize for the array any more and really has to iterate over the array.

Comment: Yeah, i seen, but it gives me an error:
parent = parent.Skip(20);
I am writing mine "parent" array, but it gives me:
Cannot impilicitly conver type |Enumerable<string> to string[]

Comment: You need a additional variable stored as `var parent = parentArray.AsEnumerable();` for this solution to properly work. Of you have a look at my answer that works around all that ;)

Comment: @Ch00pi Oh, sorry, I´ve updated it. Simply add `ToArray()`.

Comment: @Nitram's solutions works better because i am looking about performance as well. Your answer is also good, but for small array. However i have to say thanks to you too :)
Great job and fast reaction! Continue on this way! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a for loop on the parent array and add the element inside the array to a string like the following

```
String str="";
for (int i=0;i<count(parent);i++){
   str+=parent[i].tostring();
}
```

Then make a new string array and at the first index put the str variable...
Hope this help you if this what u r asking for.

Comment: What is `count()` function ?!

Comment: I assume you mean `parent.Count()`?  why not just use `parent.Length` ?

Comment: Count return the size of the array...i use it in c#, in java is. Lenght and in php also count.

Comment: Yup that what i mean...i personally use the count method

Comment: This works but it stores all elements from the parent array to one string variable. It is not usefull in my case because i have got more then 4 milion elements in the parent array. This will take too long

Comment: If you want you can make something more advance...you can split your parent array into many child array then make a threads in which each thread make the above for loop and then join the returned string from all the threads in one string...but this is not easy way....

Comment: @amirbayan for operations as easy as what is required to do here using loads of `Task`s or `Thread`s is not only a lot more complex but also a lot slower. Especially if you have to maintain the order.

Comment: Actually the thread will make as many as for loops at the same time so i dont think it will be so slow...i actually make the same proses look like the one he is asking..